# Media resource http://url/file.mp3 could not be decoded

Tags: asp.net, html, audio, lan

I'm installing a website on lan. Before that, I had an online version of it and it was fine.
When installed on the network lan, everything was fine. but there is a problem that audio is not working (all). I hit f12 on firefox and:
"Media resource http: //url/audio/file.mp3 could not be decoded."
I tried different browsers, but still fails. I tried on another computer in the network spread, still fails.
Please help me, even though I'm not the IT staff, but I had to finish it at the request of my boss.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends how you have it setup

if you have a network harddrive it should be working.

if you have a Nas server you will need to configure it for media streaming.

if you have a web server (Apache/Lamp) it will depend on what you are using,
You will need to post : OS, Hardware, Network config, and so on for me to tell you the problem.
Hope this helps :)

Reply

I would recommend one of these:

Install ubuntu then [Plex](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/plexmediaserver/) and your done
Or
  Install ubuntu then [follow these](https://www.howtoforge.com/creating-a-home-media-and-file-server-with-ubuntu) instructions.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your cmt. 
Os : Windows server 2008.
IIS,
Hardware : I dont know :(
Network config : server ip : 192.168.20.2 :(

Comment: Ok first i would recommend you change the os to Ubuntu linux

Comment: Its light weight and better suited as a server.  I'm sorry to say i don't have much experience on windows server,  Also are you going to be using this on the lan only and do you want to be able to access it as a external hdd?